# How to replace entire values in a specific column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to replace and entire value in a column (`pet`). The value ‘dog’ is repeated 85 times in that same column. If I wanted to replace it with ‘cat’ how would I do that but just in a that single column (pet)?

I tried with…

```
SELECT pet REPLACE(pet, ‘dog’, ‘cat’)
FROM Animals
```

Error message

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Are you trying to `update` the actual data stored in the table, or are you trying to `select` it so that the consumer of your query sees this replacement?

Comment: So what's not working with your query? What is "Error message" supposed to mean? You are obviously missing a comma after `pet` and smart quotes `‘’` should not be used.

Answer (score 1):

[`REPLACE()`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_replace.asp) in SQL will replace all instances of a specific sub-string within a string column value. But when used in a `SELECT` it only affects the output for that query, it will not update the source table.

The following should return all pets, and in the second column the *dogs* should be *cats*:

```
SELECT pet, REPLACE(pet, ‘dog’, ‘cat’) as newPet
FROM Animals
```

But `REPLACE()` is really designed for replacing 'dog' inside of a longer string, for instance to change `thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog` to `thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazycat`

It should still work for your simple scenario but it will change a `dogfish` into a `catfish` and that might not be appropriate.

The other way to do a conditional replacement is with [`CASE`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp)

```
SELECT pet
     , CASE pet 
           WHEN ‘dog’ THEN ‘cat’
           ELSE pet 
       END as newPet
FROM Animals
```

> In these examples the replacement is shown as a separate column, just to demonstrate the output side-by-side with the source column, but you can use the column *alias* to return the calculated column *instead* of `pet`
>
> ```
> SELECT CASE pet 
>            WHEN ‘dog’ THEN ‘cat’
>            ELSE pet 
>        END as pet
> FROM Animals
> ```

If you want to permanently update the values in the source table, then combine either of these options with an `UPDATE` statement, the simplest form would be this

```
UPDATE Animals SET
    pet = 'cat'
WHERE pet = 'dog'
```